# token endpoint using windows integrated security

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, jwt, access-token

i want to implement a token endpoint that grant tokens using windows integrated security, i found this tutorial below:

https://www.teamscs.com/2016/07/token-based-active-directory-authentication-using-owin/

it provides token based on windows user name and password, is there a way to develop similar endpoint without asking the user to enter his user name and password.

thank you and best regards.

Answer (score 0):

It is not only an implementation question. Your browser (IE, Edge, Chrome at least) will always ask username and password if your Internet Options/Security/Internet Zone/User Authentication/Logon is not set to Automatic logon with current user name and password. But is you set it, it works like a charm.